# How do I make a piecewise constant formula term?

Tags: r, splines

I can produce a model matrix for a piecewise linear spline like this:

```
>     k=seq(0,8,by=2)
>     x=seq(0,6,by=1)
>     bs(x, degree=1, knots=k, Boundary.knots=c(min(k),max(k)))
       1   2   3   4 5 6
[1,] 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0
[2,] 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0 0 0
[3,] 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0 0
[4,] 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0 0
[5,] 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0 0
[6,] 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 0 0
[7,] 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0 0
```

But degree 0 splines (i.e. step functions) are not allowed:

```
> bs(x, degree=0, knots=k, Boundary.knots=c(min(k),max(k)))
Error in bs(x, degree = 0, knots = k, Boundary.knots = c(min(k), max(k)): 
  'degree' must be integer >= 1
```

Is there an orthodox way to construct these in R, preferably one that can be used as a model formula term? I'm sure I could hack something but I'd like the idiomatic way, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut`:

```
> data.frame(x,cut_x=cut(x, breaks=k,include.lowest=T))
  x cut_x
1 0 [0,2]
2 1 [0,2]
3 2 [0,2]
4 3 (2,4]
5 4 (2,4]
6 5 (4,6]
7 6 (4,6]
```